# terminate called after throwing an instance of out_of_range

Tags: c++, palindrome

I am trying to do a palindrome check for input string, which means:

```
`"Anna"` returns `true`,
`"ada"` returns `true`,
`"1ada1"` return `true`
```

`"ABJKkjBa"` return true,

Spaces and symbol such as ",.[];" do not count. Only comparing the letters and numbers.

Here is my program:

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    getline(cin,input);
    if(isPalindrome(input))
        cout << "it is palindrome phase, or words." << endl;
    else
        cout << "it's not palindrome phase, or words." << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(string input)
{
    string TemStore_1; //only letter, number will be store in here.
    string TemStore_2; //storing TemStore_1 data other way around.
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        if((input.at(i)<58) && (input.at(i)>47)) //catching number from 0-9
            TemStore_1+=input.at(i);
        if((input.at(i))<123 && (input.at(i)>96)) //catching letter from a-z
            TemStore_1+=input.at(i);
        if((input.at(i)<91) && (input.at(i)>64)) //catching letter from A-Z, and change it to a-z
        {
            input.at(i)+=32;
            TemStore_1+=input.at(i);
        }
    }
    for(int j=TemStore_1.length();j>-1;j--)   //backwards writing the TemStore_1 into  TEmStore_2
    {
        TemStore_2+=TemStore_1.at(j);
    }
    if(TemStore_1==TemStore_2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

at the end i got out of range error... dont know which part goes wrong..

Comment: can u please post the error as i get it?

Comment: So, probably at(i) or at(j) is accessing something it shouldn't?

Comment: So run this in the debugger, find out what threw the exception and what's out of range, figure out why it's out of range, and figure out how it got there. We're unneeded.

Comment: Given your requirements, you don't need any extra strings and you don't need two loops to see if a word is a palindrome.  You're doing too much work.  One thing, I recommend you use `isalpha` and `isdigit` found in `<ccytpe>` to see if a character is alpha or digit, instead of using hardcoded ASCII numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
for(int j=TemStore_1.length();j>-1;j--)
```

starts at `TemStore_1.length()`, which causes `out_of_range` when used with `TemStore_1.at(j)`.

This is the first error I noticed; it may not be the only error in your code.

Comment: i can't let the second for loop, int j equals TemStore_1 length??